# Merge Text with object

Tags: python, text-object

Is it posible to merge a text with a object?

when i select both of them and then *Object > join* its not working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? - Please add an image to your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post   You would need to use Object > Convert > Mesh on your text before merging but that might not give you the results you are expecting.